# navigation dropdown not working with timeOuts

Tags: javascript, jquery

So jQuery and `setTimeOut` is eluding me! and I appeal to the kind nature of the Stack community for help.

I am creating a bespoke drop-down navigation and having a few issues implementing `setTimeOut` to the script so that the menu has time-out in its response.

I shall go into more detail regarding the time-outs.

The menu needs to have a time-out on `mouseenter` so the user can accidentally hover over a link and not trigger the drop-down; currently that is set to 400ms. I also want a time-out that allows the user to `mouseleave` the drop down and have 1000ms to hover back to the drop down before the drop down hides.

The caveat of this is that putting the time-outs in stop the drop-down from seamlessly switching between drop-downs with no flickering.

If one drop-down is visible and the user mouses to another top level link (parent, i.e. "services") the visual of the drop-down (its container) shows and only the data within the drop-down changes.

I hope this covers the requirements of the script, if not please ask me to elaborate.

JSfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/ATqqv/8/

And for purists or peeps who cannot visit the JSfiddle site here is my JS code.

```
function responsive_navigation() {
    var hover, $this;

    $target = $("header nav > ul > li");

    $target.on('mouseenter click', function (e) {
        $this = $(this);

        if(hover) {
            clearTimeout(hover); // Cancel the timeout to hide the menu
            hover = null;
        }

        hover = setTimeout(nav_show, 400);

    }).on('mouseleave', function () {
        //clearTimeout(hover);
        //hover = setTimeout(nav_hide, 1000);
        nav_hide();
    });

    // Show the menu relative to user actions
    function nav_show() {
        $this.addClass('active');
        $this.children('.dropnav').show();
    }
    // Hide the menu relative to user actions
    function nav_hide() {
        $this.children('.dropnav').hide();
        $this.removeClass('active');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    responsive_navigation();
});
```

Thank you in advance any and all that help and contribute to an answer.

Comment: Have added a big update to the code and updated the jsfiddle link to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/DA4cv/8/

```
function responsive_navigation() {

var menuItems = $('header nav > ul > li');
var dropDowns = $('.dropnav');
var showTimer = null;
var hideTimer = null;

// hover over nav li
menuItems.on('mouseover click', function(){ 

    clearTimeout(showTimer);           
    clearTimeout(hideTimer);

    var mi = $(this);
    showTimer = setTimeout(function(){nav_show(mi);}, 400);
    menuItems.removeClass('active');
});

// end hover on nav li
menuItems.on('mouseleave', function(){

    clearTimeout(hideTimer);

    var mi = $(this);
    hideTimer = setTimeout(function(){nav_hide(mi);}, 1000);
});

// hover over dropdown
dropDowns.on('mouseover', function(){
    clearTimeout(hideTimer);
});

// end hover on dropdown
dropDowns.on('mouseleave', function(){
    var dd = $(this);
    hideTimer = setTimeout(function(){nav_hide(dd.parent());}, 1000);    
}); 

// Show the menu relative to user actions
function nav_show(menuItem) {
    dropDowns.hide();
    $(menuItem).children('.dropnav').show();
    $(menuItem).addClass('active');
}

// Hide the menu relative to user actions
function nav_hide(menuItem) {
    menuItem.children('.dropnav').hide();
    menuItem.removeClass('active');
}  

}

$(document).ready(function () {
    responsive_navigation();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, however it does not do what the question asked for. The drop down needs to stay visual as the user hovers a new link, instead of hiding and showing (flickering) also I asked for a solution to allow the user to browse off the drop down for a max of 1000ms and still be able to come back to hover the same drop down. Please re-read my original question.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I have tested yours and @DanielGimenez and yours is the most fluid, especially with the transition of link hover to link hover.

Comment: I have found a slight issue with the code and was wondering if you could help again? If the cursor runs over a parent link but mouses out before the trigger of 300ms then the drop down still appears and it should not. I ask this now as I have noticed your active on the site atm. Thank you.

Comment: OK all you need to do is clear showTimer in the mouseleave function. Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DA4cv/9/

Answer (score 1):

The key here is all about managing your delayed executions.

In the events I make sure I cancel any impending opposite actions that are the opposite.  If the current action is not already impending, and is necessary then I begin the timer that will call the appropriate ui function.

I clear all timeouts it the ui functions in case they get called in some other manner than the events.  If this isn't an issue, you can remove any instances of `cancelAction()` and just stop a hide action for the active menu when another menu is being shown.

```
var $parent = $("header nav > ul");

$parent.children('li').on('mouseenter click', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    // cancel hiding if we left and cameback in time
    cancelAction($this, 'hover_hide_to'); 
    if (!actionImpending($this, 'hover_show_to') && !$this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.data('hover_show_to', setTimeout(function() { nav_show($this); }, 400));
    }
}).on('mouseleave', function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    cancelAction($this, 'hover_show_to');
    if (!actionImpending($this, 'hover_hide_to') && $this.hasClass('active')) {
        $this.data('hover_hide_to', setTimeout(function() { nav_hide($this); }, 1000));
    }
});

// returnts the impending action timer id.
function actionImpending($elem, name) {
    return $elem.data(name);
}

// clear timeout for element
function cancelAction($elem, name) {
    clearTimeout($elem.data(name));
    $elem.data(name, 0);
}

function cancelAllActions($elem) {
    cancelAction($elem, 'hover_show_to');
    cancelAction($elem, 'hover_hide_to');  
}

// Show the menu, hiding the active menu.
function nav_show($elem) {
    cancelAllActions($elem);
    var $active = $parent.children(".active");
    if ($active.length > 0) {
        nav_hide($active);
    }
    $elem.addClass('active').children('.dropnav').show();
}

// Hide the menu
function nav_hide($elem, delay) {
    cancelAllActions($elem);        
    $elem.removeClass('active');
    $elem.children('.dropnav').hide();
}
```

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ATqqv/13/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and your explanation, I would give you a tick also if I could, however @LeeBailey has the link hovers working smoother when you navigate from one parent link to another.